# How to make image zoom and drag-select with Ruby Gtk?

Tags: ruby, user-interface, imagemagick, gtk, rmagick

Currently, I am capable of changing images in the image window by refresh/reload with button clicks etc.
I am however unable to figure out how to make drag select with Ruby-Gtk or even that it is possible.
Basically, I want to make something like [this](https://theputterer.files.wordpress.com/2011/10/initialpointset.png) where you can zoom-in and zoom-out of an image and then use the mouse pointer to drag and scroll to view the image.
How do I go about doing that?
Any hints to useful functions and examples are very welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried writing a sample.(not drag)

```
require 'gtk3'
path = ARGV[0]

win = Gtk::Window.new('MyApp')
win.signal_connect('destroy') { Gtk.main_quit }

box = Gtk::Box.new(:vertical)

scr = Gtk::HScale.new(0.1, 5.0, 0.1)
scr.value = 1.0
swi = Gtk::ScrolledWindow.new
swi.set_size_request(300, 300)

img = Gtk::Image.new
pxb = Gdk::Pixbuf.new(file: path)
img.pixbuf = pxb

v_old = scr.value
scr.signal_connect('value-changed') do
  v = scr.value
  pxb_resized = pxb.scale(pxb.width * v, pxb.height * v, :hyper)
  img.pixbuf =  pxb_resized

  # To keep center of image when you zoom up
  w = swi.allocation.width
  swi.vadjustment = swi.vadjustment.set_value(
    (swi.vadjustment.value + w / 2.0) * (v / v_old) - w / 2.0
  )
  h = swi.allocation.height
  swi.hadjustment = swi.hadjustment.set_value(
    (swi.hadjustment.value + h / 2.0) * (v / v_old) - h / 2.0
  )
  v_old = v
end

# packing
win.add box
box.pack_start scr
box.pack_start swi, expand: true, fill: true
swi.add img
win.show_all

Gtk.main
```

But on a Mac pixbuf has some trouble.
https://github.com/ruby-gnome2/ruby-gnome2/issues/1079
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Hi,    
Thanks a lot for this answer but it doesn't work at all in my mac. 
What should be my command line argument? 
Even though the code runs it doesn't show anything on a window.
I am using a macbook BTW.

Comment: I'm sorry. Put the image path in the argument. such as, "~/Picture/foo.png", "bar.jpg".  I know you are the creater of tensorflow.rb. I am just an amateur. Above script is just a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

> Currently, I am capable of making Image Zoom using RMagick with Ruby and changing images in the image window by refresh/reload with button clicks etc.

Could you provide a code snippet that shows how you created you image widget and image window?